# Large difference between free space reported by disk utility and Apple

Tags: macos, time-machine, disk-utility, mojave, storage

[image]

[image]

I tried deleting tm snapshots already. I had five of them. Three deleted and I cannot seem to delete the remaining two. Terminal tells me they are deleted, but I still see them when I list.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  What model computer do you have and what version of the system software?  Have you tried running First Aid in Disk Utility?

Comment: You are encouraged to search for related questions. This is come up before. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70983/large-difference-in-reported-free-disk-space?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168166/huge-inconsistency-in-disk-space-measurement-missing-50-of-the-disk?noredirect=1&lq=1  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/319759/50gb-of-disk-space-missing?rq=1

Comment: I figured out that I had to start in safe mode to be able to delete those 2 TM snapshots. I have no idea why. Deleting those snapshots solved the problem I outlined above and what was the purgeable space on my hard disk is now free space. Now, I'm not feeling so great about using TM again. Is this something I should come to expect? Should TM not be managing this stuff automatically?

Comment: @KamilMuratAydin That might make for a new question!       Glad you solved it! Mind answering it, for helping others?

Comment: I followed instructions to find and manually delete the TM snapshots from Terminal. However, there were a couple of snapshots that I could not delete. I got confirmation in the terminal that the snapshots were deleted, but when I asked for a list, I still saw them. I do not know how and why this is even possible.  Needless to say, the disk space occupied by these "impossible to delete" snapshots were not getting freed up. I had to boot in safe mode to be able to delete those persistent snapshots. That's what freed up the disk space, hence problem solved.

Comment: Using macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on an older MacBook Pro 2.5 GHz i7