# "Other" taking up over HALF of my storage space

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, storage

I've recently gotten a new computer (16" base model with 8GB GPU), and its 500GB of storage had dropped to just 80 when I checked it. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

I've checked through all my folders, and adding all the items in (from the above window) Documents -> File Browser, as well as every other unique item in the sidebar, comes to roughly 445GB. So all my files take up less than half of my storage space, while this Other takes up nearly the rest! I am unable to work productively (recording videos) as I have no room to store them. Where can I find out *what* this is, and *how* to delete/remove/edit its contents? This problem didn't occur on my other computer (also running Catalina).

## Edit

I have tried these solutions from the duplicated question and from the [Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8464016), and neither of them have worked, even after restarting multiple times. How can I remove, or even access, this storage space?

```
sudo tmutil  listlocalsnapshotdates / |grep 20|while read f; do tmutil deletelocalsnapshots $f; done
tmutil  listlocalsnapshotdates / |grep 20|while read f; do tmutil deletelocalsnapshots $f; done
```

From duplicate:

```
tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
tmutil deletelocalsnapshots <snapshot number>
```

One snapshot failed to delete entirely - I wonder if this is the one causing the oversized storage?

[image]

I state once more - the solutions listed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261252/system-storage-on-macos-sierra-is-470gb) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8464016) did not help at all, if anything worsening the problem (the used space is now 287GB). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Another edit - DaisyDisk also did not show these files:

[image]

Comment: -18 [How do I ask a good question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you [thoroughly searched for an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search) before asking your question? The same question asked over and over again...

Comment: @klanomath That solution didn't work for me - I now have a 297GB "Other" storage space, even after completing all tmutil commands (which, by the way, failed to delete a local snapshot as it has an "invalid date"). The duplicate did not fix my problem - as such, can my question please be reopened?

Comment: I neither voted to close nor closed the question. But you can add your findings (=all steps you have undertaken to solve your problem (& failed)) to the question and hit the [reopen] button. Please also check the links of [jmh's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378682/93229).

Comment: @JBDouble05 DaisyDisk seems to indicate that everything is ok and you've got over 200 Gb of free space. If your Mac is not behaving like it's full: slowing down, reporting errors, then I'd say there's no problem here.

Comment: [How to thin your local Time Machine Snapshots on macOS High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309143/) .. [Gigabytes of disk space shown as hidden space in DaisyDisk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44877/gigabytes-of-disk-space-shown-as-hidden-space-in-daisydisk) I know that latter is not directly applicable. ... [I had to boot in safe mode to be able to delete those persistent snapshots.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371063/large-difference-between-free-space-reported-by-disk-utility-and-apple#comment497604_371063)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Daisy Disk](https://daisydiskapp.com) and it will give you a pictorial view of your drive and what is taking up space. It has a free trial so you can use it without buying it.  There is also a free app called Disk Inventory X which does about the same but lists the sizes of everything it "sees". It also makes a colored map of you disk. I highly recommend you use these to scan your disk.

[How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5353/313842)
 and linked: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/5353

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was really stuck trying to find out what that 'Other' meant and was able to spot those large folders taking space using the free trial of Daisy Disk. I have created this account just to thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I find Apple's breakdown of Storage to be neither reliable nor informative.

If you're running out of space and can't explain why, then first thing to do is to [boot into Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262). Then Restart normally. This process may let the OS do some housekeeping, deleting temporary files and some caches.

Next, use an app like [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more), or [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com). These will show you the contents of your entire drive, sorted by size. You can then dive into the biggest folder, and see what the biggest sub-folder is, and so on, until you identify what's using up the space.

Now comes the tricky part: Obviously, you can delete your own large files - documents, videos, etc; but some large files created by the OS or installed by applications may cause problems if removed, depending on what they are. So some caution and checking needs to take place.

For that reason, and others, I would not recommend using apps that claim to 'clean', 'purge', or otherwise maintain your Mac.

Also, don't try to delete Time Machine local snapshots unless the dates are more than 24 hours old.

If you're working with large video files, it's probably best to get a high-speed USB or Thunderbolt external drive and use that as a 'workspace' drive.