# Other data taking up to much space on mac, can't figure out what this other data is

Tags: macos, hard-drive, storage, dropbox, flash-memory

I found out my company's dropbox was syncing everything to my mac, I had selective sync on but somehow this changed. I then uninstalled dropbox to stop this syncing as choosing selective sync didn't seem to help. I then deleted my dropbox folder, and emptied trash can. But i still see 291 in other data being used up but that dropbox folder is gone. I have a feeling that is the dropbox data and didn't properly erase.

[image: Mac Storage]

What can i do to clean up files on macOS Catalina?

Comment: Let me know if you’re not on Catalina with an edit and possibly comment on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you get [OmniDiskSweeper.app](https://www.omnigroup.com/more) and run it on your main drive. it will list the items and their size on the disk sorted by size. You can look for items that take up a lot of disk space and go down the directory tree from there to find the large memory users. Its a free app.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when spotlight doesn’t or can’t fully classify all the files. I like to use Finder to calculate folder sizes and also give time for spotlight to catch up:

1. Set the Mac to not sleep for a couple hours and close and reopen the About this Mac storage window
2. While leaving the info window up, Open finder and look at the Users folder
3. Select list view (Command-2)
4. Select Finder show view options (Command-J)
5. Check Calculate all sizes
6. Click size column until the list is sorted by size descending
7. Click open the triangles to explore where the largest folders reside

[image: Finder window showing sort by size, descending]

[If you can’t find the files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378681/other-taking-up-over-half-of-my-storage-space), maybe try an app like [Daisy Disk](https://daisydiskapp.com/) which has a demo version on their web site and also a version on the Mac App Store.