# "Other" storage macOS

Tags: macos

More than half of my hard disk space is occupied by "other" storage, how can I find and delete those files? some of it is probably garbage left from deleted or unused software.

Answer (score 1):

One safe boot can clean a lot of space, so restart and hold shift. Then log in and check, restart from safe mode and continue if needed.

---

I like following the mange your storage section here to locate and
delete things. It sorts by size so you can quickly scan and move on
if any one category won’t free up the space you want cleaned.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996

Once that is done, go to reduce clutter and start cleaning. Or choose a third party tool if you prefer another tool. ["Other" taking up over HALF of my storage space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378681/other-taking-up-over-half-of-my-storage-space)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this article: [Clean Up Other Storage on Mac](https://macpaw.com/how-to/clean-up-other-storage-on-mac#:%7E:text=Simply%2C%20Other%20storage%20on%20Mac%20consists%20of%20files,that%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20fit%20into%20the%20main%20macOS%20categories.)