# Only see 70gb of space even though I have 250 gb hard disk Macbook air

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, mojave, partition

recently I messed around with my disk utility I am not sure what I did, but after doing whatever it is that I did I am only seeing 69.14 gb of space out of 250gb. Here is the image
[image]

I tried to go into the recovery mode to reinstall the os from scratch (catalina, the current os is mojave), but apparantly it is still only showing 69.14 gb of storage in recovery mode and I cannot even install on that due to insufficient memory space. I would highly appreciate if you could guide me in the right direction with solving this problem.

UPDATE - Here is the list of diskutil
[image]

UPDATE 2 - 
The following image is disk utilit > View > Show all devices
[image]

Comment: Could you attach an image of DiskUtility or `diskutil list` (terminal)?

Comment: @amdyes I updated the post with diskutil list

Comment: Thanks for the update of the question. Whenever possible copy/paste text instead of images, it makes it easier for people with screen readers. It also will ensure that the search function is aware of it.

Comment: Launchpad -> Other -> Disk Utility. View -> Show All Devices. Select the root of the list. What does it show?

Comment: @amdyes I have updated the question again with the image you asked for

Comment: @nohillside I will keep that in mind next time. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: By 'select the root of the list', I mean selecting 'Apple SSD SM0256...' in the left list.

Comment: @amdyes I have replaced it what you asked for

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help exactly. You might try https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/319764/110185. Be careful with the device name '/dev/disk0sN'. The ultimate solution is of course backup all data, erase the whole disk (not only the volume) and re-install macOS. On a Mac with T2 chip, allow External Boot from Recovery before erasing the disk.